# react-native-router-flux onright implementation to change the state variable

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am trying to make right button ('Add') on navigation bar using react-native-router-flux. When I press this Add button, CategoryList state 'addVisible' should set to false.

```
const scenes = Actions.create(
<Scene key="root">
    <Scene key="CategoryList" component={CategoryList} title="Category" initial rightTitle="Add"  onRight={() => { console.log('context'); }}/>
</Scene>
);

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import categoryReducer from './CategoryReducer';
import routerReducer from './RouterReducer';
const reducers = {
  categoryReducer,
  routerReducer
}
const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducers);
export default rootReducer;

export default class index extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router scenes={scenes}/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}


export default class CategoryList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state.addVisible = true;
  }
}
```

Kindly assist to meet the requirement.